# JSON Schema Validation helper method

Tags: java, json, validation, helper

This is what I wrote to validate JSON to the given schema.

```
public void validateJsonSchema(ObjectNode jsonSchema, ObjectNode json) throws InvalidRequestException {

    String errorMessage = null;

    if (json != null) {

        if(jsonSchema == null) {
            errorMessage = "json exist in request but there is no schema to validate it against";
        }
        else {
            try {
                JsonSchema jsonSchema = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault().getJsonSchema(jsonSchema);
                ProcessingReport processingReport = jsonSchema.validate(json);

                if (!processingReport.isSuccess()) {

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    processingReport.forEach(jsonError -> sb.append(String.format("[%s] ", jsonError)));

                    errorMessage = String.format("json validation failed. Errors: %s", sb.toString());
                }

            } catch (ProcessingException e) {
                errorMessage = String.format("json validation threw ProcessingException. Error Message: %s", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    if (errorMessage != null) {
        throw new InvalidRequestException(errorMessage);
    }

}
```

Here are few things that I had in my mind while writing this code:

1. I don't want to return anything from the method. Schema is either `valid` or `invalid`. In case of `invalid`, I just throw an exception. Since it's part of a `Helper` class, I think it's okay to put some business logic (throwing exception) with in this code.
2. I like 1 point of return or 1 point of exception throwing. Thats why I am using `errorMessage` to capture any error and if it exists, throw it at the end. By this approach, the code readability is much better.
3. The `jsonSchema` and `json` both are optional. In case if `json` doesn't exist, there is no point of getting into validation.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to Julien Rousé and you, I'm rather against the "1 point of return" policy. It doesn't make it more readable. It might make it a bit easier to formally prove correctness of the code, but I have never seen someone do that outside of an academic context.

As it is now, when looking at what would happen if the `json == null` you'd first encounter the `if(json != null)` line. Then you scroll down 20 or more lines to find the end of that `if` block finding that there's no `else` block. But the method doesn't end here yet. There's another `if (message != null)` line where I forgot if I had encountered any initialisation in the meantime so I have to go over the entire method again to see if it is null or not ...

Compare that with a method that starts with:

```
public void validateJsonSchema(ObjectNode jsonSchema, ObjectNode json) throws InvalidRequestException {
    if (json == null) {
        return;
    }
```

By writing in this "return as early as possible" style, you immediatly see that empty `json` objects are always valid. If at some point it's clear what the result of the method should be, then I want that to be clear explicitly at that point. I don't want to tire myself constantly looking up and down the method to see if I didn't miss anything (for example: was this `message` really still null when we got here?).

That's why I would prefer to structure the method like this:

```
public void validateJsonSchema(ObjectNode jsonSchema, ObjectNode json) throws InvalidRequestException {
    if (json == null) {
        return;
    }

    if(jsonSchema == null) {
        throw new InvalidRequestException("json exist in request but there is no schema to validate it against");
    }

    try {
        JsonSchema jsonSchema = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault().getJsonSchema(jsonSchema);
        ProcessingReport processingReport = jsonSchema.validate(json);

        if (!processingReport.isSuccess()) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            processingReport.forEach(jsonError -> sb.append(String.format("[%s] ", jsonError)));

            throw new InvalidRequestException(String.format("json validation failed. Errors: %s", sb.toString()));
        }

    } catch (ProcessingException e) {
        throw new InvalidRequestException(String.format("json validation threw ProcessingException. Error Message: %s", e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

I'd say this is more readable and especially easier to find out what the result is of the special cases. Not that I had any trouble reading/understanding your code ofcourse. I just prefer the way that takes a little bit less effort to understand completely.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a bullet list so I try to comment each bullet separately

1. I have mixed sentiment about this. I do agree with  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77361/3729797) stack overflow post, I'll quote

   > An exception is thrown when a fundamental assumption of the current code block is found to be false.

   Here you want to validate a Json schema, so your code validate it or not, but if the parameter for JsonSchema is `null` it goes contrary to what is expected so I believe you are right to throw the exception.

   But for the same reason, I believe you should not return an exception when `processingReport.isSuccess()` returns false. My take on this would be to return `true` of `false` to indicate if validation is ok or not. That might have to do with personal taste.
2. I like it the same way, but sometimes it's good to throw an exception as soon as you can. Here I it doesn't really matter, your code is readable and understandable, do as you please.
3. I see nothing wrong with the fact that if `json` is `null` you don't check for `jsonSchema`. The only thing maybe I would be wary of is because you don't return a value, you consider `json == null` the same as a valid `json`, which might be a bit confusing.

Comment: thanks for the input. Regarding point 1. If i return `true` or `false` i would nee a mechanism to let callee know what were json errors. In my case, i need to tell clients that json was invalid because of these errors. thats why i am building an error message and throwing an exception which contains those errors. **regarding 3**: This is correct assumption. Since if `json` is null, the rest of the business logic should continue. the `json` is an optional parameter to api. so a null json means that there were no validation errros so we can continue to process remaining request.

Comment: Maybe you could return an object containing a `boolean` for knowing if validation is `true` or `false`  and a list of error if needed? This way exception would be thrown only when something exceptional happen, as I believe they should be. Or maybe an another way of returning your errors without using exception? (Your solution is fine, I'm nitpicking a bit since you asked a review ;) )